# Puppeteer: How can I get the browser object assigned to another variable without it being undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, chromium

I've been working on a project that uses puppeteer to open browser pages, I want to be able to later on add more pages to the same browser instance, so I want to know what is the best way to return the browser object, or assign it to an array of browsers in order to store it. In summary, once I run the browser, I want to be able to open pages as new tabs later on if the user decides to. Any ideas of how to do this? Thanks in advance.

## My code is as follows:

**index.js (main program file)**

```
let browsers = [];
async function runBrowser(pageID,browserID) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        "headless": false,
        "defaultViewport": null,
        "args": ['--start-maximized'],
        //"userDataDir": FULLPATH,
    });
    success = true;
    browsers[browserID] = browser;
//CHANGE THE PAGE THAT OPENS
    switch(pageID){
        case 0:
        login.openCursosPuntoD(browser);
        break;
        case 1:
        facebook.openFacebookPuntoD(browser);
        break;
        case 2:
        instagram.openInstagramPuntoD(browser);
        break;
        case 3:
        twitter.openTwitterPuntoD(browser);
        break;
        case 4:
        youTube.openYouTubePuntoD(browser);
        break;
        case 5:
        webPage.openPaginaWebPuntoD(browser);
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
};
runBrowser(1,1);
//HERE ONCE I RUN THE BROWSER I WANT TO BE ABLE TO OPEN PAGES AS NEW TABS IN IT LATER ON IF THE USER DECIDES TO
console.log(browsers[1]);
```

***NOTE** `The console.log(browsers[1]);` Returns undefined in the console, so the browser object is not being passed on.

**cursosPuntoD.js (an example of a page function file)**

```
function openCursosPuntoD(browser){
actions.runPage('https://xxxxx.org/login/index.php',true,browser);
};
module.exports = {
    openCursosPuntoD,
};
```

**actions.js (has the actions that the browser can perform)**

```
//FUNCTION TO OPEN PAGES
async function runPage(url,doLogin,browser){
    const page = [];
    const pageNumber = (await browser.pages()).length+1;
    page[pageNumber] = await browser.newPage();
    await page[pageNumber].goto(url);
      
if(doLogin == true){
    var user = getUsername();
    var pass = getPassword();
    login(user,pass,page[pageNumber]);
}
else{}
}

//FUNCTION TO GET USERNAME

function getUsername(){
    var content = fs.readFileSync('../data/user.txt','utf8');
    var result = JSON.parse(content);
    var username = result[Object.keys(result)[0]];
    return username;
}

//FUNCTION TO GET PASSWORD

function getPassword(){
    var content = fs.readFileSync('../data/user.txt','utf8');
    var result = JSON.parse(content);
    var password = result[Object.keys(result)[1]]
    return password;
}

async function login(user,pass,p){
    await p.type('#username', user);
    await p.type('#password', pass);
    await p.click('#loginbtn');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I run the browser, I want to be able to open pages as new tabs later on if the user decides to.

You mention pages, but you're not even using [`browser.newPage()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.4.1/docs/api.md#browsernewpage) method anywhere.

If you want to open multiple pages in tabs, this is a simple example that works like that:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

    const pages = [];
    pages.push(await browser.newPage());
    pages.push(await browser.newPage());

    await pages[0].goto('https://google.com');
    await pages[0].screenshot({path: 'google.png'});

    await pages[1].goto('https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer');
    await pages[1].screenshot({path: 'puppeteer.png'});

    await browser.close();
})();
```

It's pretty much the example from getting started section from Puppeteer's github page [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#getting-started).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @pavelsaman , I do have the pages, let me update the code to show all my files.

Comment: Ok, you're opening new pages inside function `runPage()` that defines array `page` inside it, so you don't have access to it outside the function.